# Arduino Uno Bluetooth connection

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect two Arduino Unos with Bluetooth modules (HC-06 and HC-05). Does anyone know the steps required to do that?

I still haven't figured out:

- How to pair the two Bluetooth devices, and;
- How to pair each Bluetooth with each Arduino.

If you have any useful tutorials, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice example for Arduino here.

[Connecting 2 Arduinos by Bluetooth using a HC-05 and a HC-06: Pair, Bind, and Link](http://www.martyncurrey.com/connecting-2-arduinos-by-bluetooth-using-a-hc-05-and-a-hc-06-pair-bind-and-link/)

The Uno works the same way as the board in the example.

Arduino 1

[image: Arduino 1]

Arduino 2

[image: Arduino 2]